# Name of a particular improper integral

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, fresnel-integrals

I am curious if there is a particular name for this,
$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\xi^2}d\xi$. I think it might be related the Fresnel integral but I cannot see it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\omega$ is a square root of $-i$, 
$$\int_{-R}^R \exp(ix^2)\; dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\omega} \text{erf}(\omega R)$$
The limit as $R \to \infty$ is then $(1+i) \sqrt{\pi/2}$.